# How to get common roots of unity of $ z^{6}=1 $ and $ z^{21}=1 $?

Tags: complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

How to get common roots of unity of $z^{21}=1$ and $z^{6}=1 $ for $ z\in\mathbb C $?

I know that $ z^{n} =1 $ has roots $ z=e^{\frac{2\pi k }{n}i} $ where $ k\in \{0,1,2,...,n-1\} $

Comment: Do you mean $z^6=1?$

Comment: I have corrected!!

Comment: Find the roots of $z^3$ as $\left(z^3\right)^2=z^6$ and $\left(z^3\right)^7=z^{21}$.

Comment: Note that $z^{21-3\times 6}=z^3=1$.

Comment: In $z^{21}=1$ for what values k we have $e^{i\pi/3}$?? And how

Answer (score 3):

$$  \gcd( 21, 6 ) = ???    $$

$$ \frac{ 21 }{ 6 } = 3 +  \frac{ 3 }{ 6 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 6 }{ 3 } = 2 +  \frac{ 0 }{ 3 } $$ 
 Simple continued fraction tableau:
 $$ 
 \begin{array}{cccccc}
 & & 3 & & 2 & \\ 
  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 }   &   \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & &   \frac{ 3 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 7 }{ 2 }  
 \end{array}
 $$ 
 $$  $$ 
 $$ 7 \cdot 1 - 2 \cdot 3 = 1 $$

$$  \gcd( 21, 6 ) = 3  $$
 $$ 21 \cdot 1 - 6 \cdot 3 = 3 $$

==================================================================

a different example:

$$  \gcd( 7654321, 1234567 ) = ???    $$

$$ \frac{ 7654321 }{ 1234567 } = 6 +  \frac{ 246919 }{ 1234567 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 1234567 }{ 246919 } = 4 +  \frac{ 246891 }{ 246919 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 246919 }{ 246891 } = 1 +  \frac{ 28 }{ 246891 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 246891 }{ 28 } = 8817 +  \frac{ 15 }{ 28 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 28 }{ 15 } = 1 +  \frac{ 13 }{ 15 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 15 }{ 13 } = 1 +  \frac{ 2 }{ 13 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 13 }{ 2 } = 6 +  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 2 }{ 1 } = 2 +  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 } $$ 
 Simple continued fraction tableau:
 $$ 
 \begin{array}{cccccccccccccccccc}
 & & 6 & & 4 & & 1 & & 8817 & & 1 & & 1 & & 6 & & 2 & \\ 
  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 }   &   \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & &   \frac{ 6 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 25 }{ 4 }   & &   \frac{ 31 }{ 5 }   & &   \frac{ 273352 }{ 44089 }   & &   \frac{ 273383 }{ 44094 }   & &   \frac{ 546735 }{ 88183 }   & &   \frac{ 3553793 }{ 573192 }   & &   \frac{ 7654321 }{ 1234567 }  
 \end{array}
 $$ 
 $$  $$ 
 $$ 7654321 \cdot 573192 - 1234567 \cdot 3553793 = 1 $$

Answer (score 1):

$$ \begin{align}\{ z : z^6=z^{21}=1, z\in\mathbb C \}&\Longleftrightarrow \{ k : k=o(z),\ k|6,\ k|21 \}\\
&\Longleftrightarrow\{ k : k=o(z),\ k|\gcd (6, 21) \}\\
&\Longleftrightarrow\{ k : k=o(z),\ k|3 \}\\
&\Longleftrightarrow\{ k : k=o(z),\ k=1\ \text{or}\ k=3 \}\\
&\Longleftrightarrow\{ z\in \mathbb C : z^3=1 \}\\
&\Longleftrightarrow\{ z : z=1\ \text{or}\ z=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}\ \text{or}\ z=e^{\frac{4\pi i}{3}}  \} \end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

$z$ will satisfy both of $z^{21}=1$ and $z^6=1$ iff $z^3=1$.  One direction is trivial,  the other follows from $z^6=1\implies z^{21}=z^3$.

Thus $ z\in \{ 1,e^{\frac{2\pi i}3},e^{\frac{4\pi i}3} \} $.